# Fast 8-bit checksum algorithm for heterogenous tuples

Tags: c, hash, simd, checksum

Suppose I have triplets containing 3 heterogenous integer types (`int16_t`, `int32_t`, `int64_t`) and I would like to compute an 8-bit unsigned checksum for these 3 values. Assume all of the values have uniform distribution across all the significant bits so we cannot cheat by truncating any of the values at concatenating them.

What's a fast way for me to compute a checksum with relatively low collision rate and non-cryptographic properties? I'm guessing I can concatenate the bytes and use a variant of Fletcher's checksum or Pearson hashing, but all of the implementations I've seen of those seem dated and I'd like to see if I can further exploit any SIMD or properties of modern (Skylake) architecture.

I'm also aware of MurmurHash but it doesn't have an 8-bit implementation.

Comment: This is really too broad and will call for opinion. You should test. Murmur is good, so is Spooky, openSSL has a good one as well. You will just have to test on your implementation, Look at the `clock_gettime` function on Linux or `QueryPerformanceCounter` on windoze to time the hashing. (and checksum and hashing are not exactly the same, so asking for checksum and then discussing hashing is a bit unclear)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't think Murmur or Spooky have 8 bit implementations?

Comment: Understood, but all hash algorithms (discussed) are open-source, so you can tailor (hack) them to handle a byte at a time. I was just looking at murmur, yale_hash, djb2, and fnv1. All wouldn't be too difficult to modify to take a byte at a time.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I appreciate your sentiment. I hope you see that my question is not a matter of how to benchmark an implementation that exists, but rather that I don't have such an implementation in the first place. Also this is not about taking a byte at a time but rather producing an 8 bit checksum itself. And for example, changing any of them to a SIMD implementation is nontrivial.

Comment: No, no, I get what you are asking, yes, I get the goal is a 8-bit (hash or checksum) for each of the tuples. I'm just suggesting that a question asking for 'the fastest X' generally is not met favorably. I don't ding people for asking, but you may want to further expand on what you have tried and the results you have gotten because currently there is no benchmark to beat in your question which makes is a bit broad. Good luck.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Understood, thanks. I've reworded my question for any fast algorithm. My best implementation is just a hand-unrolled Pearson hash, unfortunately.

Comment: `Assume all of the values have uniform distribution across all the significant bits ...` :: anything goes; just add them (this is what the IP checksum does) or xor them. `... seen of those seem dated` Because there is no better solution.

Comment: The distribution of errors is also relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern x86 has very fast [CRC32C (hardware instruction added in SSE4.2)](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/CRC32).  You might get good results from concatenating the int32 and int16 into a zero-extended int64_t, and using two CRC32C instructions to accumulate a single checksum.  To get the compiler to do this for you, use intrinsics from imintrin.h: `unsigned __int64 _mm_crc32_u64( unsinged __int64 crc, unsigned __int64 data )`.

According to [Agner Fog's instruction tables](http://agner.org/optimize/), `crc32` has 1 per clock throughput and 3 cycle latency on Skylake, so feeding it 2x 8 bytes and getting a 32-bit result should only take 2 uops / 6 cycle latency.  Feed it the `uint64_t` first so concatenating the uint16 and uint32 are off the critical path, i.e. create instruction-level parallelism between the shift/or and the first `crc32`.

---

**Then horizontally XOR the crc32c down to 8 bits**:

```
uint32_t crc = my_object_crc32(&my_object);
crc ^= crc>>16;
crc ^= crc>>8;
crc = (uint8_t)crc;
```

Horizontal xor to mix the bits of a wider crc / hash / checksum into an 8-bit value is applicable to any hash function you want to use.

---

**Or simply take the low byte of the CRC32C**.  IDK how much if anything you gain from XORing all 4 bytes down to 1.  Again, viable with any multi-byte hash function.

**You could even just horizontally XOR all the bytes in your input**.  e.g. load with a 16-byte SSE2 load, and mask off the padding bytes, then `pshufd` / `pxor` down to 8 bytes, `pshuflw` / `pxor` down to 4 bytes. 
 Then another `pshuflw` / `pxor` down to 2 bytes, and `movd` to integer for the final shift / xor.  (Or you could `movd` to integer earlier, especially if the compiler has BMI2 `rorx` to copy-and-shift with one instruction).

Comment: Wow. Fantastic answer. The `_mm_crc32_u64` + XOR approach does it in 61-65 cycles on a Haswell E5 (17~ ns) with 2 x 64-bit integers and 1 concatenated 64-bit integer. Just for completeness, the header is `nmmintrin.h`.

Comment: @Katie: It's easier to just always include `immintrin.h` instead of worrying about which ISA extension goes with which header.  Or does your compiler not include crc32 intrinsics in `immintrin.h`?

Comment: Interesting, https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=crc32&expand=1246 seems to suggest I needed this from `nmmintrin.h` and no, my compiler does not include CRC32 intrinsics in `immintrin.h`.

Comment: @Katie: `immintrin.h` uses `#include` to include all the previous headers.  Works for me with gcc/clang/icc/msvc: https://godbolt.org/g/GaKTLB.  And BTW, see my last update: you might just take the low byte of the CRC32C instead of horizontal xor, assuming that CRC32C sufficiently mixes bits already.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention that all of the values are uniformly distributed across all of your bits, you can simply choose *any* byte in your tuple as your 8-bit hash, ignoring the remaining bits, which is essentially free. The result is a perfectly uniform hash function, which is the best possible (it will have a collision probability of 1 in 256, which is the lower bound for unpredictable input).

You only need a "better" hash function if you input bits are somehow non-uniform (which is the case the overwhelming majority of the time for real data that isn't just random numbers, but I guess your situation is different).